# Poker game get next card ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a basic poker game. I would like the card draw functionality to take place on the server. I have never done any programming in AJax, but it sounds like what i need to make this work. I have two main questions. A If I make 2 ajax calls to the NextCard() FUNCTION  in my DECK.php CLASS will i get results from the same DECK instance or would i get results from two different DECK objects. B How do i call CurrentCard() using ajax? Thanks

```
<?php
include 'Card.php';

class Deck {
    private $deck = Array();
    private $currentindex = 0;

   function __construct() {
        $x=0;   
        $suit = 's';            
        for($x=0;$x<52;$x++){
            if($x <39) $suit = 'h';
            if($x <26) $suit = 'd';
            if($x <13) $suit = 'c';         
            $deck[$x] = new Card($suit,$x % 13);    


        }
   }        

    function CurrentCard(){
        return $deck[$currentindex].toString();     
    }

    function NextCard(){
            $currentindex++;
        return $deck[$currentindex].toString();

    }
    function Shuffle(){
        $x=0;
        $temp;      
        for($x=0;$x<52;$x++){
            $Rnumb = rand (  0 , 52);               
            $temp = $deck[$x];
            $deck[$x] = $deck[$Rnumb];
            $deck[$Rnumb] = $temp;
        }

    }  

}
?>
```

Comment: Starting from the point that a PhP object die when the page stop runs... The object it's from the db or is a Javascript Object or what else?

Comment: How are you calling `NextCard`? Do the same for `CurrentCard`.

Comment: As suggested by Goikiu , you would need a way to "store" the deck on the server. If you're going to a player vs computer game, it could be in a session variable. If you want PVP, it needs to be in a database, in file, or anything that persists on the server...

Comment: why not doing everything in js?

Comment: @LouisXIV i want it to be PVP. If i do it in Javascript the players will have access to my deck object.

Comment: In this case, I think Bartude is giving you the best way to go. Use [serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to store your array and unserialize to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

1st ans: different result
2nd one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post( "Deck controller link like base_url(). Deck/CurrentCard", function( data ) {
        // This will be $deck[$currentindex].toString() received from controller funct.    
        // Use it on any view element(need view codes to complete:()
    });
});
</script>
```

You can also post json data from that controller func. In that case you need to specify it in the ajax call.